# Стоит ли так активно использовать аннотации как в приведенном примере

Tags: java

Вроде как в самих нативных библиотеках Java нет такого частого использования аннотаций, чтобы каждый геттер или сеттер был подписан, или каждый включенный класс. Или я ошибаюсь?

```
@Path("/hello")
public static class Resource {

    @Inject Counter counter;

    @GET
    public String get() {
        return "Hello, User number " + counter.getNext();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не понятно, что Вы имеете ввиду под нативными библиотеками. Как правило сторонние библиотеки, как раз предоставляют функционал по работе с такими аннотациями, они вполне могут содержать аннотированные классы (методы, поля). Если они не нуждаются в аннотациях, то их там и нет. Платформа (JDK) не запрещает Вам лепить аннотации на каждый класс, метод или поле класса. Главное четко понимать, что за той или иной аннотацией стоит, как она будет обработана, и во что может превратиться Ваш код после компиляции, например. Если такого понимания нет, то аннотации воспринимаются как "черная магия" и возникает мнение что это зло.

Comment: видать нет у меня четкого понимания, надо пройтись по теме